# Please help me with this sentence "細かいところは後で決めましょう"

Tags: meaning

I got bumped into unknown sentence

```
細{こま}かいところは後{あと}で決{き}めましょう
```

It suppose to mean "Let's decide the details later"
I don't know what's ところ mean. I read around here on the forum and apparently a lot of meaning, like "place", and "about to" but its still doesn't make a lot sense.

Please help me clarify that, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe thinking about it as [spots](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%89%80) will help? Like in a sense of "imaginary" spots in a plan for a trip or something like that.

[細かいところ](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B4%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84%E4%BA%8B) - specific "spots" e.g. the details

Note: You can also use 細かいこと like in the link above.

Comment: Thanks!
What I didn't understand if it is a really specific spot. "Minor place we will decide later". It's not like the real minor thing they will decide must be the place, it's only a metaphor right?

Comment: Yeah "spot" in the abstract sense, could be anything, if we go with the trip planning example, it could be anything like, "how to get there",  "budget", "what to eat" etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

ところ has many meaning as you noticed. This ところ means 部分(part), 箇所(point).